# When should I create a primary key on multiple columns?

Tags: primary-key

I'm interested to know in which case I should create a primary key on multiple columns and why ?

To be more specific about my question, I want to know  what are the advantages and disadvantages of primary key on multiple columns in terms of performance.

I did some research and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750335/can-sql-table-have-multiple-columns-with-primary-key) where someone is saying

> Another good question is SHOULD a primary key be multiple columns. :) – Sonny Boy Nov 17 '09 at 17:31
>
> Well, that's a different question, and the answer is NO, NOT EVER, AND
> IF YOU DO I WILL HUNT YOU DOWN AND HURT YOU. Just a personal
> preference, of course :-) – Stu Dec 4 '09 at 16:46

Despite the joke, there should be some good reason on why one shouldn't use primary key on multiple columns but I couldn't find any answer.

---

I was wondering about this because I have a concrete problem.
Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_travel_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `day` date NOT NULL,
  `origin` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `destination` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ukey` (`id_user`, `day`, `origin`, `destination`)
)
```

In this table, for each user I have some data for each day and for each  travel from `origin` to `destination`.

I need this table because it's very easy to use `WHERE` clause on it.
However, the numbers of line in this table are just insane. Usually, a user has ~50 origins and ~100 destinations.
With 30 days filled & 200 users, there's ~30 million lines in my table.
Because each user has around ~150000 lines, I had to create some tools for them to edit/delete/add lines in group.
And, because of these tools, users tends to delete old lines and create a whole bunch of new lines. This leads to a very fast increase of my primary key.
While it is not a problem now, it could be one pretty soon.

So, since I don't use the id on this table, I was wondering if I could do something like :

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`, `day`, `origin`, `destination`)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404040/how-do-you-like-your-primary-keys#answer-404462) is also quite useful but didn't help with my problem

Comment: Why is a "fast increase" of a primary key a potential problem? Also see [Performance of multi field primary key or contrived key](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14697/performance-of-multi-field-primary-key-or-contrived-semi-artificial-key?rq=1)

Comment: @JohnM It is a potential problem because there's a limit to an int. While I can use a bigint instead it just delay the problem. When my Id reach it's max value, I'll not be able to insert any more row.

Comment: Do you really plan on having more than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 rows in your table, even accounting for frequent deletes? There's also a [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) as an option if so.

Comment: To be honest, those two SO questions are only mildly useful.  My take: if you don't plan to join other tables to this one (on the primary key), just use the natural key.  If you do, use a surrogate key (`bigint` if `int` is not enough).

Comment: @JohnM [What's better here - a single column or multicolumn primary key?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63080/whats-better-here-a-single-column-or-multicolumn-primary-key) while this answer give some general advice, it doesn't explain in terms of performance why having a multicolumn primary key is worse than a completly **unused** id. It just state _Per-group serials are typically expensive, pointless effort_. Yes, maybe, but isn't it better than an unused id ? If not, why ?

Comment: @dezso by natural key, do you mean my multiple column primary key ?

Comment: @GaryOlsson yes

Comment: A single column primary key is best.  A comment:  Although the PK is often made the clustered index as well, it is certainly possible to make the PK a UNIQUE index, then you can make the independent CLUSTERED INDEX include several columns, if there is truly a need for that.

Comment: Generally, an associative or bridging table is a good candidate for a compound primary key. For example, if multiple books have multiple authors, you can have a bridging table with only 2 columns: `bookid` and `authorid`. By designating _both_ columns as a primary key, you guarantee uniqueness of the entries (that is, you never mention a book/author combination more than once).